# Possible to query for embedded documents and get only those documents rather than where at least one?

Tags: python, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a Dataset with an individual athlete_id, season and a list of different events and results the athlete did.

```
[{'id':'123',
    'season':'2019',
    'event_type1':[
    {'Date':'20 Oct 2019,'Location':'somewhere1','result':'182'},
    {'Date':'20 Oct 2019,'Location':'somewhere2','result':'184'}], 
    'event_type2':[
    {'Date':'20 Oct 2019,'Location':'somewhere1','result':'182'},
    {'Date':'20 Oct 2019,'Location':'somewhere2','result':'184'}]
]
```

Thanks to stackoverflow and documentation I came so far to get all documents with **at least one time** somewhere1 in event_type1.

```
query = {
    '$and': [
        {'season': 2019},
        {'event_type1':{ '$elemMatch' : {'Location':'somewhere1'}}}
        ]
    }
db.col.find(query)
```

However, I want to get **event_type1** and **somewhere1 results only**.

At my current knowledge level I would fall back to loop over the retrieved dictionaries, because I did not find a smarter way in the documentation yet.

**Question:** Is it possible to retrieve only the required dicts rather than where at least one exists?

*Further information, if required:
In my use case the event_types contain spaces and are not the same for all athletes. Probably because of the spaces I did not get an $unwind approach to run.*

Comment: You could `"$project"` `"event_type1"` and `"$filter"` it for the `"somewhere1"` condition.

Comment: Thank you, @rickhg12hs I will research that '$project' approach tomorrow.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I tried it with those examples, but it did not work. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to `find` the documents you want and *project* the fields the way you want.

```js
db.collection.find({
  "season": "2019",
  "event_type1.Location": "somewhere1"
},
{
  "id": 1,
  "season": 1,
  "event_type1": {
    "$filter": {
      "input": "$event_type1",
      "as": "event",
      "cond": {"$eq": ["$$event.Location", "somewhere1"]}
    }
  }
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7PddTvXDtHu).

Comment: Thank you. I learned a lot. However, I used my aggregate solution, because I was able to work with / change field values.

Comment: @TheArmbreaker Yes, aggregation pipelines are more flexible and powerful.  I only used `find` here because it was used in your question and discussed in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I found following solution. It provides a list of relevant embedded documents (dicts) for each ID.

```
pipeline = [

    {'$unwind': 'event_type1'},
    {'$match':{
        'event_type1.Location':'somewhere1'
    }},
    {'$group':{
        'new_id':'$id',
        'new_event':{'$push':'event_type1'}
    }} 
     
]
myList = list(mycoll.aggregate(pipeline))
```

*Somehow the spaces in the event type  don't disturb anymore - must have been a typo in the past.*